# iOS - send email from mobile app

Tags: ios, email

I want to send an email through my mobile app. I am using following code to achieve this

```
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"usr@example.com"];

 MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:@"Test subject"];
    [mc setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But when I run this code, app crashed without any output on console. Any reason for this?

Comment: If there is a crash there is some kind of crash report. Perhaps it hit a debugging breakpoint?

Comment: Are you testing it in a real device or in the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing it in a real device make sure there is at least one email account registered in the device. And, surround your code with try catch to detect the cause of the crash

Comment: It is not appropriate to use `try/catch` here. Use the debugger to determine the cause of the crash.